I lost/deleted "My Applications" icon
I recently deleted some files and folders on my 24.04 Ubuntu, and it appears that I have deleted the icon or folder for My Applications (you known the bright orange circle with the A).
Does any one know how to recover this without having to do a full reinstall?

Have you just deleted the icon or removed the shortcut? What do you currently see?

Clicking the bright orange icon with a white letter A in the middle opens the App Center in Ubuntu 24.04 and shows the icon for it in the Dock. Use the snap-store command to launch the App Center. To make it appear in the Dock permanently right-click the App Center icon and select Add to Favorites.

I think the A stands for App and the part of the icon that looks like a 90° counterclockwise rotated C but is really the handle of a shopping bag stands for Center.
